Why is this list index out of range for a return statement but not for a print statement?
The goal: Given an integer array nums of length n and an integer target, find three integers in nums such that the sum is closest to target.
Return the sum of the three integers.
I've written up a potential solution. At the end, I have a list of lists solution. When I try to print the first entry of the first list in solution, I get the expected (and correct) result. I can manipulate this data with no problems.
class Solution:
    def threeSumClosest(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> int:
        from operator import itemgetter

        solution = [sum([nums[x], nums[y], nums[z]]) for x in nums for y in nums for z in nums if x != y != z != x]

        solution = [[x, abs(x-target)] for x in solution]
        sorted(solution, key=itemgetter(1))

        print(solution[0][0])

However, the moment I actually set a return value for the function, like so
class Solution:
    def threeSumClosest(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> int:
        from operator import itemgetter

        solution = [sum([nums[x], nums[y], nums[z]]) for x in nums for y in nums for z in nums if x != y != z != x]

        solution = [[x, abs(x-target)] for x in solution]
        sorted(solution, key=itemgetter(1))

        return solution[0][0]

I get this error
IndexError: list index out of range
           ~~~~~~~~^^^
    return(solution[0][0])
Line 10 in threeSumClosest (Solution.py)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    ret = Solution().threeSumClosest(param_1, param_2)
Line 42 in _driver (Solution.py)
    _driver()
Line 53 in <module> (Solution.py)

I get this error even if I try to return a dummy value, like return 0. So clearly what I've written doesn't work, but I cannot figure out where the problem lies.

sorted() function returns a new sorted list; it doesn't sort in place.

@MarcinOrlowski Makes sense, but I'm still getting the error even when fixing this with solution = sorted(solution, key=itemgetter(1))

The code in the error message (return(solution[0][0])) isn't the same as you show in the question (return solution[0][0])…?!

@deceze when I run the code, I am given the error specified in the OP. This is in an in-browser IDE.

Assumption: you're running this on LeetCode or some such platform, which is testing your code with many different inputs. One of the inputs is an empty list, and it fails in that case because it doesn't take it into account.

Why do you have filename inside brace bracket in line 10? threeSumClosest (Solution.py)

"I get this error even if I try to return a dummy value, like return 0" — How do you get an index error when not trying to access any index?!

@deceze Correct. However, after adding a line to handle that case, I am still getting the same error. I added if len(nums) == 0: return 0 at the beginning of the function.

I don't believe it. Please show an input where the print succeeds but the return fails.

The main issue is in this line:
solution = [sum([nums[x], nums[y], nums[z]]) for x in nums for y in nums for z in nums if x != y != z != x]

This is problematic because it's using the values in nums as indices, not as the actual numbers to sum. This will cause an IndexError if any value in nums is greater than or equal to the length of nums.
Also the condition x != y != z != x doesn't guarantee that x, y, and z are different indices which was your former intention. In Python, a != b != c is equivalent to (a != b) and (b != c), which doesn't imply a != c.

I see. So maybe a list comprehension isn't the best way to go about this? Also, doesn't x != y != z != x guarantee that z != x? Since it explicitly says so at the end: z != x

People sometimes oddly think that you must use list/dict comprehension otherwise it's crap and not "proper" Python code. This is in general complete B/S - newbies got confused, longer logic is unreadable. I'd suggest you make the logic that works first (nested loops - whatever you like). Once you got that working, you can optimize or fold it back to comprehension (if that would make any sense).

As explained in my aswer, no - the expression x != y != z != x does not actually guarantee that z != x, because Python evaluates chained comparisons, and it would  interprets this expression as (x != y) and (y != z) and (z != x). Do the check yourself for the values x=1, y=2 and z=1 then print your original check and then print(z != x) :) If you want your check corrected, you should write it explicitly like  x != y and y != z and z != x.

How are (x != y) and (y != z) and (z != x) and x != y and y != z and z != x different?

they aren't. I edited wrongly.

Not sure what that means. Do you still think that x != y != z != x doesn't ensure they're all different?

What happens in the case x == y == z?
The solution is an empty list! That is the source of the index error. You can try updating the logic to consider indices instead.

This allows it to run, thanks. My solution is still wrong but at least the code can run!
